# friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle conflicts with sebastian/exporter

Tags: composer-php, ckeditor, symfony-3.4

I have problems installing FOS/ckeditor-bundle after succesfully removing egeloen/ckeditor-bundle.
(I did it the way suggested in: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCKEditorBundle/blob/HEAD//docs/migration.rst )

The output is:

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle      
Using version ^2.1 for friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle 2.1.0 conflicts with sebastian/exporter[1.2.2].
    - friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle 2.1.0 conflicts with sebastian/exporter[1.2.2].
    - friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle 2.1.0 conflicts with sebastian/exporter[1.2.2].
    - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle ^2.1 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle[2.1.0].
    - Installation request for sebastian/exporter == 1.2.2.0 -> satisfiable by sebastian/exporter[1.2.2].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I also tried with:

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle:1.2.0
```

But I get the same error. Is there a special version for symfony 3.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your other dependencies probably require `sebastian/exporter` < 2.0 which `friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle` does not support.

You can get the list of packages that require `sebastian/exporter` with

```
composer why sebastian/exporter
```

which then you can use to upgrade (so they require newer `sebastian/exporter`) or remove packages to enable installation of your bundle.

Comment: Seems that my phpunit/phpunit uses sebastian/exporter.
I removed phpunit/phpunit and I can now install ckeditor.

Comment: PHPUnit 5.7 is the first version which supports `sebastian/exporter` 2.0, so maybe you could try upgrading to that version instead of removing it.